# Finding the last occurence of "." or ":" java

Tags: java, regex

I have IP addresses in the following forms:

1) `20fe:f9..d3:93b1.58418`

2) `100.253.13.145:1346`

I would like to write a Java program to identify the last occurrence of `"."` or `":"`.

**Basically, I am trying to truncate whatever occurs after the last "." or ":"**

However, I have no idea how to write such a program. Some example codes will be helpful

Comment: Have you seen `String.lastIndexOf`?

Comment: A regex might not be necessary for this.

Comment: when you are looking for the last occurrence of either "." or ":", are you looking to have their indices in the IP address string?  What are you trying to do with the information, as this will greatly influence your approach...

Comment: @user1769197: Even after my comment, you have no ideas whatsoever? I'd expected that to be a reasonable hint.

Comment: String have `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` and `substring` methods. Try to combine them.

Comment: Where is my comment? :D

Answer (score 1):

For finding the last index of some character, String has a built-in method:

```
String.lastIndexOf(int ch)
```

So in your case:

```
yourVariable.lastIndexOf('.');
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29

Then you can use this index to get the last part of the address(if that's what you want to do)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
String [] parts = yourString.split("[.:]");
System.out.println("Last element is : " + parts[parts.Length -1]);
```